# How to generate MD5 hash for the first n bytes in sh scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, md5sum

I have the following php code line:

```
$md5_code = md5(file_get_contents($filePath, FALSE, NULL, 0, n_bytes));
```

that generates a MD5 hash code of a file's first `n_bytes`.

I would like to make a similar executable script/program, that gets the file and exports in a text file the MD5 hash code generated from the first `n_bytes`.

I think I need to mention that the script should work on both Windows and Linux machines.

The script can work something like this:

- Move the selected file where the script is
- Execute script
- Get generated code from the newly made text file

Is this even possible ?

Comment: I'm hoping this will help me find incomplete downloads for which I have the full download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have functional Linux utilities on your window box, you can use bash and md5sum. You do not need to create a new file, as 'md5sum' can process data on stdin.

```
# Modify variable to use parameters/values as needed.
filename=...
n_bytes=100
out_file=md5.out
head -c "$n_bytes" "$filename" | md5sum | awk '{ print $1 }'  > "$out_file"
```

Comment: It works. That is great ! But why does it add white space and a line `-` after the hash code ?

Comment: The output for md5sum include the file name ('-' for stdin). awk can help remove it. See modified code

Comment: `head -c` is non-standard; consider using `dd if="$filename" bs="$n_bytes" count=1` instead.

Comment: @chepner What are you saying ? Non-standard ? How is one better than the other ?

Comment: The [POSIX standard for `head`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html) neither requires support for `-c` nor defines what it means if it is supported. Any given implementation of `head` may omit it or define it to mean something other than what you are assuming it means. The [`dd`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) command I shows, on the other hand, is precisely defined by POSIX. As long as you are using a POSIX-compliant implementation, it should work.